# I deleted sqlite3 and after Migration I keep receiving: OperationalError at / no such table: core_item

Tags: python, django

I wanted to clean my database and start over so I deleted `sqlite3` and after deleting it I ran
`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` but I keep receiving an error `OperationalError at / no such table: core_item`

I am not sure why is this happening so I am copying the traceback call:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 157, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\core\views.py", line 82, in get_context_data
    context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 119, in get_context_data
    paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 69, in paginate_queryset
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 70, in page
    number = self.validate_number(number)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 48, in validate_number
    if number > self.num_pages:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 97, in num_pages
    if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 91, in count
    return c()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 392, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 504, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 489, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1097, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py", line 176, in execute
    return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py", line 117, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projectz 4.3\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: core_item
[08/Aug/2020 22:04:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 211611
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the migration folders (that you deleted) and run `python manage.py migrate` again.

Answer (score 0):

You have already deleted the databases so i m guessing **init** file too ?
Can you try creating a new super user by

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and then run the makemigrations and migrate command after creating a superuser